# Vaadin7 dynamically populate combobox from Rest API

Tags: combobox, vaadin, vaadin7

I would like to dynamically populate a combobox from Vaadin7 using a rest API. The API returns a lot of values if not filtered.

This is the basic idea I have. I know that the version of Vaadin contains better ways to bind data but I need to use this is a new-old legacy system.

My main problem is that the event does not fire when typing new values and also I am not sure how to get the current value in the combobox so I can send it as a filter to the API

Here is the code

```java
@SpringUI
public class MainView extends UI {

  @Autowired
  private NameService nameService;

  private ComboBox comboBox;

  @Override
  protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    VerticalLayout verticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();

    comboBox = new ComboBox();
    comboBox.setContainerDataSource(getDataSource());
    comboBox.setItemCaptionMode(ItemCaptionMode.PROPERTY);
    comboBox.setItemCaptionPropertyId("name");
    comboBox.setImmediate(true);

    comboBox.addValueChangeListener(event -> {
          // When I manually enter a property I want to go to the server
          // Rest API and get a new List of names
          String filter = event.getProperty().toString();
          comboBox.setContainerDataSource(getDataSourceWithFilter(filter));
        }
    );

    verticalLayout.addComponent(comboBox);
    setContent(verticalLayout);
  }

  // Get 20 names with a filter
  private BeanContainer<String, Name> getDataSourceWithFilter(String filter) {
    BeanContainer<String, Name> container = new BeanContainer<>(Name.class);

    container.setBeanIdResolver(Name::getId);
    // this list comes from a webservice API
    List<Name> names = nameService.fetch(filter, 0, 20).collect(Collectors.toList());
    container.addAll(names);

    return container;
  }

  // Get 20 (default) names without filtering
  private BeanContainer<String, Name> getDataSource() {
    return getDataSourceWithFilter("");
  }
}
```

Comment: Is `addValueChangeListener`fired? If not, then you would need to extend the ComboBox component to fire at the appropriate time(s)

Comment: It has bean a long time with V7, so IIRC: combo box only triggers the value change on an actual value change.  it has it's own filter capabilities and can pass it down to the backing container of the CB.  so you would have to implement a container that talks to your backend.  there are some examples in the v7 docs how to write your own containers for DBs, which should be a good base to adopt.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how expand the combobox? I have the Vaadin7 book but I don't even know where to start looking. I am not that of an expert in Vaading. @cfrick I know this is just a legacy app.

Comment: Do I understand correctly: you're implementing an autocomplete field? Sort of like Google's main page search box or similar, where typing anything automatically updates the list of options? If so, ComboBox is not maybe the best option. There are add-ons for this purpose in the Vaadin Directory easily found with the "autocomplete" keyword; this one: https://vaadin.com/directory/component/autocompletefield-for-vaadin seems to support Vaadin 7. There are a couple of options for V8 as well which might be easily downgradeable to V7.

Comment: @ollitietavainen yes I need to do an autocomplete. Unfortunately I am bound to the Vaadin7 version and to a Combobox. :(

Comment: Sorry I'm in a hurry right now and can't write a proper answer. As some other comments have already pointed out, you need to create a custom Container implementation that receives filtering instructions from the ComboBox and delegates those to your REST API. Creating such a Container implementation manually is quite difficult, but you can use this addon that helps you do it relatively easily: https://vaadin.com/directory/component/lazy-query-container

Comment: There's also https://vaadin.com/directory/component/asyncfiltercombobox which may be interesting

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution by creating my own Combobox and overriding the **changeVariables** method. Thanks to all of you who pointed me to the right direction.

So it looks like this:

```java
public class FilteringComboBox extends ComboBox {

  @Override
  public void changeVariables(Object source, Map<String, Object> variables) {
    if (variables.containsKey("filter")) {
      final String text = variables.get("filter").toString();
      fireEvent(new TextChangeEvent(this) {

        @Override
        public String getText() {
          return text;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCursorPosition() {
          return text.length();
        }
      });
    }
    super.changeVariables(source, variables);
  }

  public void addTextChangeListener(TextChangeListener listener) {
    addListener(TextChangeListener.EVENT_ID, TextChangeEvent.class, listener, TextChangeListener.EVENT_METHOD);
  }

  public void removeTextChangeListener(TextChangeListener listener) {
    removeListener(TextChangeListener.EVENT_ID, TextChangeEvent.class, listener);
  }
}
```

And then I used it in the main UI as follows:

```java
@SpringUI
public class MainView extends UI {

  @Autowired
  private NameService nameService;

  private FilteringComboBox comboBox;

  @Override
  protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    VerticalLayout verticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();

    comboBox = new FilteringComboBox();
    comboBox.setContainerDataSource(getDataSource(""));
    comboBox.setItemCaptionMode(ItemCaptionMode.PROPERTY);
    comboBox.setItemCaptionPropertyId("name");
    comboBox.setImmediate(true);

    comboBox.addTextChangeListener(event -> {
          String filter = event.getText();
          comboBox.setContainerDataSource(getDataSource(filter));
        }
    );

    verticalLayout.addComponent(comboBox);
    setContent(verticalLayout);
  }

  private BeanContainer<String, Name> getDataSource(String filter) {
    BeanContainer<String, Name> container = new BeanContainer<>(Name.class);

    container.setBeanIdResolver(Name::getId);

    List<Name> names = nameService.fetch(filter, 0, 20).collect(Collectors.toList());
    container.addAll(names);

    return container;
  }
}
```